# f# deedle aggregate row values base on column key

Tags: f#, deedle

say I have the following `Frame`,

```
type Person = 
   { Name:string; Age:int; Comp1:float; Comp2:float }

let peopleRecds = 
    [ { Name = "Joe"; Age = 51; Comp1=12.1; Comp2 =20.3 }
      { Name = "Tomas"; Age = 28; Comp1=1.1; Comp2 =29.3 }
      { Name = "Eve"; Age = 2; Comp1=2.1; Comp2 =40.3 }
      { Name = "Suzanne"; Age = 15; Comp1=12.4; Comp2 =26.3} ]
let peopleList = Frame.ofRecords peopleRecds
```

What I would like to do is to sum `Comp1` and `Comp2` columns into a new column for `peopleList`, and the `n` for `Comp(n)` is undecided at the moment, so I cant just to know only sum two columns, there might be `Comp3`, `Comp4`, so have to base on regular expression, something like key is leading with `Comp`.

It seems what I should do is to `mapRowValues` on each row

```
   peopleList?TotalComp <- peopleList |>Frame.mapRowValues(
                                          fun row -> 
                                              (do something to sum up)
                                         )
```

However I am not sure how to operate at the row level here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is planned to increase the number of 'Comp' , it might be better to put them in an array:

```
type nPerson =  { Name:string; Age:int; Comp:float[] }

let npeopleRecds = 
    [ { Name = "Joe"; Age = 51; Comp = [| 12.1; 20.3 |] }
      { Name = "Tomas"; Age = 28; Comp = [| 1.1; 29.3  |] }
      { Name = "Eve"; Age = 2; Comp = [| 2.1; 40.3  |] }
      { Name = "Suzanne"; Age = 15; Comp = [|12.4; 26.3 |] } ]
```

Then you can easily add a column with the sum of:

```
let npeopleList = Frame.ofRecords npeopleRecds

npeopleList.Format() |> printfn "%s"

let sumseries = npeopleList.GetColumn<float []>("Comp") |> Series.mapValues(fun x -> x |> Array.sum)

npeopleList?TotalComp <- sumseries

npeopleList.Format() |> printfn "%s"
```

Print:

```
     Name    Age Comp
0 -> Joe     51  System.Double[]
1 -> Tomas   28  System.Double[]
2 -> Eve     2   System.Double[]
3 -> Suzanne 15  System.Double[]

     Name    Age Comp            TotalComp
0 -> Joe     51  System.Double[] 32,4
1 -> Tomas   28  System.Double[] 30,4
2 -> Eve     2   System.Double[] 42,4
3 -> Suzanne 15  System.Double[] 38,7
```

**Edit:**

If the change the fields in the Person record is unacceptable - you can use filters:

```
let allSum = 
    peopleList.Columns
    |> Series.filter(fun k _ -> k.StartsWith("Comp"))
    |> Frame.ofColumns
    |> Frame.rows
    |> Series.mapValues(Series.foldValues(fun acc v -> acc + (v :?> float)) 0.0)


peopleList?TotalComp <- allSum

peopleList.Format() |> printfn "%s"
```

Print:

```
     Name    Age Comp1 Comp2 TotalComp
0 -> Joe     51  12,1  20,3  32,4
1 -> Tomas   28  1,1   29,3  30,4
2 -> Eve     2   2,1   40,3  42,4
3 -> Suzanne 15  12,4  26,3  38,7
```